# How to define and use a related Model in Objection.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, knex.js, objection.js

Using the following code ([which uses ES6's](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field) `"type":"module"` in `package.json`), I can't seem to access the related Model `Group`:

```js
import db from "../connection.js";

import objection from "objection";
const { Model } = objection;


Model.knex(db);

class User extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "users";
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      groups: {
        relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
        modelClass: Group,
        join: {
          from: "users.id",
          through: {
            from: "users_groups.user_id",
            to: "users_groups.group_id",
          },
          to: "groups.id",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Group extends Model {
  static get tableName() {
    return "groups";
  }
}
```

If I run

```js
const myUser = await User.query().findById(1)
```

It outputs:

> User {id: 1, name: "r", email: "raj@raj.raj", username: "raj", … }

But I still can't access the `Group` relation:

```js
myUser.groups
```

Outputs:

> undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use eager loading in the query to load the desired relations.

It you are using Objection.js **v1**:

```js
const myUser = await User.query().eager('groups').findById(1)
```

And since Objection.js **v2**, `eager` was renamed as [`withGraphFetched`](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/query-examples.html#eager-loading):

```js
const myUser = await User.query().withGraphFetched('groups').findById(1)
```

---

*Extra*: Loading relations after instantiation

You can load the relations after instantiation using [$relatedQuery](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/query-examples.html#relation-find-queries). Note all instance methods starts with `$`:

```js
const myUser = await User.query().findById(1)
const groupsOfMyUser = await myUser.$relatedQuery('groups')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can `.withGraphFetched()` (or some rendition of it) be used on an an instance? For example if `myUser` was already queried without `.withGraphFetched('groups')`, can it be done after instantiation?

Comment: Yep, added to the answer :)